# How to go from dictionary to pandas DataFrame to CSV while making the dict keys the first column, not the index

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, dictionary

1. I have a dictionary of lists that I convert into a pandas DataFrame
2. I write that DataFrame to a CSV

I want the **keys** of the dictionary to be the **first column** of the DataFrame, **not the index**, because I need those values to have a column name ('ID'). I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make that happen.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_name, orient='index', columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])

df.to_csv('output_filename', sep='\t')
```

Comment: Have you tried transposing your dataframe before saving it as csv file ?

Answer (score 1):

Reset the index then don't include the newly generated sequential index in the file:

```
df.index.names = ['ID']
df.reset_index().to_csv('output_filename', sep='\t', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks, however it is crucial that the first column have the header 'ID' and I'm not sure how to make that happen with what you suggested (your code makes the header of the first column 'index'). I'm trying to do `df.reset_index()`, `df.rename(columns={'index':'ID'}, inplace=True)`, `df.to_csv('output_filename', sep='\t', index=False)`, but then the output CSV loses the first column of keys entirely.

Comment: You need to reset the index with `inplace=True` as well.

Comment: Alternately you could just do `df.index.names = ['ID']` before running the line in my answer.

Comment: When I run your code the way it is now (with `df.index.names = ['ID']`), the output CSV file has Column1: header=ID, cells=0, 1, 2, etc. Column2: header=index, cells=dict keys.